# Single band wifi extender with dedicated backhual channel, without halving user bandwidth?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, bandwidth, wireless-extender

I am trying to understand how wifi and wifi extender works on a super high level.

Some wifi extenders (such as Netgear Orbi) are advertised with tri-band, and saying a dedicated band is used for backhaul so that max client facing bandwidth will not be halved. My question here is why this can not be achieved using separate channels within a single band? I know that 2.4G band is quite limited, but the 5G band itself has many channels, for example it can hold multiple non-overlapping 160MHz channels already. The simplistic setup would be:

```
              stream A                   stream B
router/AP <---------------> extender <---------------> laptop
              channel X                  channel Y
```

where stream A is the downlink/uplink between router and extender, and stream B is the downlink/uplink between extender and laptop. Assuming stream A and B are on channel X and Y respectively, and X and Y are just two non-overlapping channels in the 5G band. Will this work?

Comment: I had never heard of tri-band (WiFi) before, so I did some digging. I postulate this triband moniker is symantics - triband is just 2 parts of the 5g band, so, I think, very similar to what you suggest. I found https://dongknows.com/dual-band-vs-tri-band-wi-fi-routers-explained/ useful in coming to this conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question here is why this can not be achieved using separate channels within a single band?

It can, and I believe that's how it is actually done.

However, you still need separate radio transmitters/receivers to properly use those separate channels simultaneously, and what "Tri-band" actually means is that the device has three Wi-Fi radio units – one for the 2.4 GHz band and two for the 5 GHz band.

In other words, they're using the term 'band' to mean something else entirely, as often happens in marketing. (Possibly because "dual-band APs had two radios, and therefore an AP with three radios must be tri-band", or something. Maybe it just sounded cool when put on a box.)

Comment: so it's more like tri-channel than tri-band? Btw, MIMO does not require multiple transmitters? for example, 4x4 MIMO requires 4 different modulations on the same channel, and one transmitter can handle all four modulations job?